Data Processing for self-report measures before conducting inferential test. Sum, mean or leave it as-is?
Consider the following scenario:
An intervention was conducted where subjects were randomly assigned to control or experimental condition. Self-Efficacy data was collected before and after the intervention. I want to see if there the intervention improved self-efficacy among participants.
Self-efficacy scale contains 6 questions on a 1-6 likert-scale response. See the randomly generated data below.



Participant
Group
Pre_Q1
Pre_Q2
Pre_Q3
Pre_Q4
Pre_Q5
Pre_Q6
Post_Q1
Post_Q2
Post_Q3
Post_Q4
Post_Q5
Post_Q6




1
Experimental
4
5
4
3
4
4
5
5
4
3
4
4


2
Experimental
5
4
4
2
4
3
5
5
5
5
4
4


3
Experimental
4
4
5
4
3
4
4
4
5
4
4
5


4
Experimental
5
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
4
4
5
4


5
Experimental
3
4
4
3
5
4
5
5
5
3
4
4


6
Experimental
5
3
4
4
4
4
5
4
4
5
4
4


7
Experimental
4
4
5
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
4
5


8
Experimental
4
3
4
4
4
5
5
3
5
4
5
5


9
Experimental
5
4
4
4
5
4
5
5
4
4
5
4


10
Experimental
5
5
3
4
4
3
5
5
5
4
5
4


11
Experimental
3
3
4
4
4
4
3
4
4
5
4
4


12
Experimental
4
3
3
3
4
4
5
3
3
3
4
5


13
Experimental
4
4
5
5
4
5
4
5
5
5
4
5


14
Experimental
4
4
4
4
5
4
4
4
5
4
5
4


15
Experimental
4
3
4
3
4
4
4
4
5
4
4
4


16
Experimental
4
5
4
3
4
4
4
5
5
3
4
4


17
Experimental
5
5
4
5
4
4
5
5
4
5
4
4


18
Experimental
4
5
4
3
4
5
4
5
4
3
4
4


19
Experimental
5
3
4
4
4
4
5
3
4
5
4
4


20
Experimental
4
4
4
4
5
4
4
4
4
4
5
4


21
Control
5
4
3
5
3
4
5
4
3
5
3
4


22
Control
4
3
4
4
5
4
4
3
4
4
5
4


23
Control
3
4
4
4
4
5
3
4
4
4
4
5


24
Control
5
4
5
4
4
4
5
4
5
4
4
4


25
Control
4
4
4
3
4
4
4
4
4
3
4
4


26
Control
4
5
5
4
3
4
4
5
5
4
3
4


27
Control
4
4
5
5
3
4
4
4
5
5
3
4


28
Control
5
5
5
4
4
4
5
5
5
4
4
4


29
Control
5
5
4
4
4
3
5
5
4
4
4
3


30
Control
5
4
4
4
3
4
5
4
4
4
3
4


31
Control
4
4
5
4
4
4
4
4
5
4
4
4


32
Control
3
5
4
4
3
4
3
5
4
4
3
4


33
Control
4
4
3
3
5
4
4
4
3
3
5
4


34
Control
4
4
5
4
4
3
4
4
5
4
4
3


35
Control
4
5
4
4
4
5
4
5
4






My question is:

Do I sum the value for pre-test and post-test and then proceed with the inferential test?
Do I take the mean value for each participant and then proceed with the inferential test?
Do I leave the values as-is for the each participant and then proceed with the inferential test?

For me, the first choice makes sense. But at the same time, I am unable to reason why the second and third option are incorrect.

Option 1 and 2 are inefficient, as you convert two values into one. Option 3 treats the observations as independent values, which they are not. You would underestimate the uncertainty and any test would end up biased towards significance.
This is precisely what repeated measures ANOVA and mixed models are for (you would include participant as a random effect).
Another important question is how to treat the Likert-scale data. It is possible that the distance between, say 3 and 4 is larger than 4 and 5. You should look into models that can handle ordinal response variables.
